# Error while building project when executing build step 'Make'

Tags: c++, qt, makefile, qt-creator

I've just installed Qt SDK 1.2.1 on my PC. I created a new project as a test:

`File > New File or Project... > Other Project > Plain C++ Project`

I chose these build settings:

[image: qt creator build settings]

Qt Creator generated this .pro file:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.cpp
```

and this main.cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The build fails:

```
13:39:35: Running build steps for project test...
13:39:35: Starting: "C:\Dev\Qt\QtSDK\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" clean
Could Not Find C:\Dev\Projects\Qt\test\debug\main.obj
    del debug\main.obj
    del debug\test.intermediate.manifest debug\test.exp debug\test.ilk vc*.pdb vc*.idb
Could Not Find C:\Dev\Projects\Qt\test\debug\test.intermediate.manifest
Could Not Find C:\Dev\Projects\Qt\test\vc*.pdb
Could Not Find C:\Dev\Projects\Qt\test\test.intermediate.manifest
Could Not Find C:\Dev\Projects\Qt\test\test.exp
Could Not Find C:\Dev\Projects\Qt\test\test.ilk
Could Not Find C:\Dev\Projects\Qt\test\vc*.pdb
    c:\dev\qt\qtsdk\desktop\qt\4.8.1\msvc2008\bin\qmake.exe -spec ..\..\..\Qt\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\msvc2008\mkspecs\win32-msvc2008 CONFIG+=declarative_debug -o Makefile test.pro
    C:\Dev\Qt\QtSDK\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Debug clean
    C:\Dev\Qt\QtSDK\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Release clean
Could Not Find C:\Dev\Projects\Qt\test\release\main.obj
Could Not Find C:\Dev\Projects\Qt\test\release\test.intermediate.manifest
    del release\main.obj
    del release\test.intermediate.manifest release\test.exp
    del ".\test.intermediate.manifest"
    del test.exp
    del test.ilk
    del vc*.pdb
    del vc*.idb
Could Not Find C:\Dev\Projects\Qt\test\vc*.idb

jom 1.0.8 - empower your cores

13:39:36: The process "C:\Dev\Qt\QtSDK\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited normally.
13:39:36: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
13:39:36: Starting: "C:\Dev\Qt\QtSDK\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" 
    cl -c -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t- -Zi -MDd -GR -EHsc -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -I"..\..\..\Qt\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\msvc2008\mkspecs\win32-msvc2008" -Fodebug\ @C:\DOCUME~1\Mitch!\LOCALS~1\Temp\main.obj.5936.16.jom
    C:\Dev\Qt\QtSDK\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Debug
'cl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
jom: C:\Dev\Projects\Qt\test\Makefile.Debug [debug\main.obj] Error 1

jom 1.0.8 - empower your cores

jom: C:\Dev\Projects\Qt\test\Makefile [debug] Error 2
13:39:36: The process "C:\Dev\Qt\QtSDK\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building project test (target: Desktop)
When executing build step 'Make'
```

I've tried running the `Qt 4.8.1 for Desktop (MSVC 2008)` batch script before starting Qt Creator and checking the `Projects > Build Settings > Build Environment > Using System Environment > Clear System Environment` without success.

My `PATH` variable after installing Qt SDK 1.2.1:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files\jEdit;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\doxygen\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Cg\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
```

My computer is running Windows XP Professional (Service Pack 2). The version of Qt Creator that ships with Qt SDK 1.2.1 is 2.4.1.

Comment: A good and valid question. However, this appears to be an install issue, and you're likely to get better help at the Qt Developer Network. There is a [thread specifically for installation](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewforum/14/).

Comment: A bug report has been created: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTCREATORBUG-7973

Comment: A work around, as noted by Sebastien in the comments of the bug report, is to run creator from the Visual Studio 2008 Command Prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `cl` is either not installed on your system, or needs to be added to the `PATH` environment variable. Try to find the `cl.exe` binary somewhere in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio [version]\` and add the directory that contains that binary to your `PATH`.

Comment: I did that (added `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin` to PATH), but get a [similar error](http://pastebin.com/Ja6ayDhg).

Comment: @Mitch can you open `Tools` -> `Options` -> `Build & Run` and then the `Tool Chains` tab and take a screenshot, please?