# QT creator setup on windows

Tags: qt

Hey guys thanks for looking at this question. I am attempting to learn some UI programming and was hoping to use QT creator to get started. I am a babe in the woods for Qt Creator 4.6.0. And I can't seem to setup QT creator to work on windows 7. When I go to *manage* the project or tools>options>build and run I really don't know what to fill out?

If all I do is create a new project and attempt to "build all" I get the error:

```
Could not determine which "make" command to run. Check the "make" step in the build configuration.
```

I found alot of post on how to fix this but I haven't figured out how to get them to work for me.

[Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44838817/could-not-determine-which-make-command-to-run-check-the-make-step-in-the-b)

[Example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49433878/could-not-determine-which-make-command-to-run-check-the-make-step-in-the-b)

[Example 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10425103/error-while-building-project-when-executing-build-step-make)

[Example 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20355562/qt-creator-compiling-error-at-step-make)

I am attempting to figure out what exactly I am doing wrong. It might have something to do with not selecting the correct compiler and Qmake file? So far what I do is.

Step 1: [Create New Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jjrze.png)

Step 2: [I then go into kit selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ue1Cz.png)

Step 3: [I select manage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zH9XS.png)

Step 4: [select the Manual(desktop) nothing is automatically populated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pu43O.png)

As for the rest of the tabs I have:

[compilers tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vAMK.png)

[debug tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvLjd.png)

[CMAKE tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AS9C9.png)

After I setup all the tabs should I have a functioning project?

Ok well after looking I guess there isn't a Qmake file installed with QT just to be clear on the installation I am wondering which of the boxes should I check during installation. It comes up like the following picture
[QT Installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNo9X.png)

Comment: You dont have a proper build kit setup or you're not building with a properly configured build kit. Check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49433878/could-not-determine-which-make-command-to-run-check-the-make-step-in-the-b/49434273#49434273

Comment: I would suggest checking the path to each one of those components. Also can you show the Qt Versions tab?

Comment: Your installation is failed. My advice is unistalling your qt. And reinstall again. You can refer [install qt](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eS7ank-qFjg), and download qt5.9.4 [here](http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.9/5.9.4/)